# Spring-web-reactive example having dependency version issue

Tags: spring-webflux

I am trying to run this example - https://github.com/joshlong/bootiful-reactive

I am facing compilation issues. What version of spring-web-reactive works with reactor-netty ?

Answer (score 0):

There have been a lot of changes lately and I think that repository hasn't been updated accordingly. Maybe open an issue on this repository directly?

Answer (score 0):

It's common to see such dependency issues in SNAPSHOT versions. You can update to the latest M2 version.

Answer (score 0):

As I known, the `spring-web-reactive` artifact was renamed to `spring-webflux` in the latest Spring 5.

If you are using Spring Boot 2, at the moment the latest milestone is 2.0.0.M4, it includes a starter for `webflux`.

Check my sample codes: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample